# Error running Firebase (using gRPC) on openjdk 11 on ARM: SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, grpc, lego-mindstorms-ev3

**Firebase** requires **gRPC**.  gRPC seems to require some type of encryption protocol that the **ev3dev** distribution is missing?  I had really hoped that getting JDK > 8 would solve the issue, but that last `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)` makes me think something fundamental isn't supported.

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-ev3)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 11.0.3+7-ev3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
robot@ev3dev:~$ java -Xshare:on -jar ev3-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:82)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at info.MYSTUFF.CloudBotDoc.<init>(CloudBotDoc.kt:54)
    at info.MYSTUFF.BasicBot.<init>(BasicBot.kt:42)
    at info.MYSTUFF.MainKt.main(Main.kt:11)
    at info.MYSTUFF.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:699)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:532)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslEngine.beginHandshake(JdkSslEngine.java:155)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:1756)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.startHandshakeProcessing(SslHandler.java:1675)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelActive(SslHandler.java:1810)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:213)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:199)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:192)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:213)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:199)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:941)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:311)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:341)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I'd expect Java 11 to work as well. The protocols/ciphers are provided by Java itself, but it is possible to limit them with configuration. That error message seems to imply trouble negotiating the version of TLS to use, which is strange since every HTTP/2 client/server is supposed to support at a common protocol/cipher. Can you point out which Firebase API you are using?

Comment: Latest firebase Admin API.

Comment: Where did you get Java 11 from? It appears Java 8+9 is installed by default on ev3dev, and that they weren't installed with dpkg.

Comment: Uhhhhh. I may have apt dist upgraded everything. Possibly better to start over with 9?

Comment: Looks like it could be "jri-11" from http://archive.ev3dev.org/debian/pool/main/j/jri-11-ev3/ and https://github.com/ev3dev-lang-java/openjdk-ev3 . Feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java and link here. For debugging, add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl before the "-jar" argument. I don't care about any of the "adding as trusted cert". I'd be making sure TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 isn't ignored.

Comment: I was wrong about Java 8+9. It does come pre-installed with jri 11. I accidentally looked at some files from my host system.